# django-dynamic-scraper : No module named django.core.management

Tags: python-2.7, django-dynamic-scraper

My experience with  django-dynamic-scraper is limited,I try to install django-dynamic-scraper with my MAC but when I finish everything I got this error :

```
File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Please I need your help and Thinks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when django is not installed on your computer. When django is not installed which means django.core.management module is also is not installed. So it didn't find this module and it gives error.
For solving this problem we should install django using pip.I don't know for MAC but for windows you install this way below

```
pip install django
```

This command will install django in your computer. If you don't have install pip. you should install pip.

Comment: But when I type 
pip freeze
I got this :
Django==1.10.6
thats mine is installed

Comment: You should install pip on mac. Do you have pip?

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: Yes I use Those Commands : 

*     git clone https://github.com/holgerd77/django-dynamic-scraper.git 
*     cd django-dynamic-scraper
*     virtualenv .
*     source bin/activate
*     pip install -r requirements.txt
*     python setup.py install
*     cd example_project
*     python manage.py makemigrations